# Laravel : How to to group collection by date with datetime field?

Tags: laravel, date, datetime, group-by

I have this Model (Match) :

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "match_date": "2021-06-12 16:00:00",
    "home": "Wales",
    "away": "Switzerland",
    "h_goals": 0,
    "a_goals": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "match_date": "2021-06-12 19:00:00",
    "home": "Denmark",
    "away": "Finland",
    "h_goals": 0,
    "a_goals": 0
  }
]
```

How I can I group them by match_date but just date format without datetime ,also the date output just be time ,something like this :-

```
[
 "date" : "2021-06-12",
  "data" :[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "m_date": "16:00:00",
    "home": "Wales",
    "away": "Switzerland",
    "h_goals": 0,
    "a_goals": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "m_date": "19:00:00",
    "home": "Denmark",
    "away": "Finland",
    "h_goals": 0,
    "a_goals": 0
  }]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using laravel collection helper methods you can transform your data as

```
$collection = collect([
    [
        "id"=> 2,
        "match_date"=>"2021-06-12 16:00:00",
        "home"=> "Wales",
        "away"=>"Switzerland",
        "h_goals"=> 0,
        "a_goals"=> 0
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 3,
        "match_date"=> "2021-06-12 19:00:00",
        "home"=> "Denmark",
        "away"=> "Finland",
        "h_goals"=> 0,
        "a_goals"=> 0
    ]
]);

$results = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $item["m_date"] =  \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item["match_date"])->format("H:i:s");
    return $item;
})->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item["match_date"])->format("Y-m-d");
})->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return ["date"=> $key, "data"=> $item];
})->values();
```